# Can't complete the Irune, Benning, and certain Citadel missions after Cereberus assaults Citadel

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm trying to complete a few of the missions that involved finding pieces during the Tuchanka mission set. Specifically:

- Benning: Evidence
- Citadel: Improved Power Grid
- Citadel: Barla Von
- Citadel: Heating Unit Stabilizers
- Irune: Book of Plenix

However when I complete the missions on Tuchanka that give me the requirement pieces (like opening up Irune and Benning for scanning, exploration), it immediately starts the "Priority: Citadel" mission set and I cannot turn any of them in.

It probably should be noted that Sur'Kesh and Palaven priority missions were already completed. As in, when I completed Tuchanka, the above listed missions are greyed out.

Aside from editing my save file to say the missions were completed, how can I do these missions without resorting to such? Is there something that I missed. Should I restart and do Tuchanka's mission set first, turn those in and then the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Priority: Tuchanka* is a turning point in ME3, because once it's over, it automatically triggers *Priority: Citadel*. During that mission, you cannot complete any other assignments. Once *Priority: Citadel* is completed, certain assignment are no longer possible to complete, due to a rearrangement of NPCs on the station.

*Benning: Evidence*, *Citadel: Improved Power Grid* and *Citadel: Barla Von* are part of those missions that cannot be completed after you've started *Priority: Tuchanka*. If you want to complete these missions at this point in your game, you will have to either load a save file prior to the start of *Priority: Tuchanka* or edit your save file. It should be noted that *Benning: Evidence* is not completed by scanning the planet but by doing the *N7: Cerberus Abductions* mission, which becomes available upon completion of either *Attican Traverse: Krogan Team* or *Tuchanka: Turian Platoon.* If you have completed that N7 mission without finding the required evidence, you should check out the Spectre Office.

On the other hand, *Citadel: Heating Unit Stabilizers* and *Irune: Book of Plenix* are impossible to complete before *Priority: Citadel* is over and you will be able to finish them afterwards.